# Simplemodal disables all widgets on page it overlays

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, simplemodal

Revising some UI software for a contract.  The page is JSP/DOJO 1.4 with text fields radio buttons and dropdowns. They have a button that pops a simplemodal box (jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.js) that shows a list of addresses the user has entered at one time or another.  When the modal is closed, all of the dropdowns no longer work in IE 7 or IE 8.
Would love to present some code, but I would have to build an example. I'm looking for a direction to look at and debug.  Firefox works perfectly here and $.browser.version is reporting the proper browser version.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All right, because this is an analysis goof, I am going to answer the question.  The call to the simplemodal code was being made from an anchor:

For some reason this works fine in FireFox but IE 7 and 8 choke on it.  Change this to:

Do The Modal

and it works everywhere.

My apologies to Mr. Martin.  I did not mean to slander his app.